# Is removing type tags idiomatic elm?

Tags: types, type-conversion, elm

I've created the following types, (eliding some unnecessary details)

```
type alias Mover =
  { x : Int
  , y : Int
  }


type Piece
  = Enemy Mover
  | Player Mover
```

And I use these functions to create them

```
enemy : Int -> Int -> Piece
enemy x y =
  Enemy { x = x, y = y }


player : Int -> Int -> Piece
player x y =
  Player { x = x, y = y }
```

But I find myself having to use this function before I can actually use them ...

```
toMover : Piece -> Mover
toMover piece =
  case piece of
    Enemy mover ->
      mover

    Player mover ->
      mover
```

... and that seems somewhat cumbersome. Is this the way I'm supposed to do this or am I making things harder on myself? I want to be able to keep a `Player` in the same list as some `Enemy` instances and sometimes be able to tell the difference between them, but also be able to write functions that work on both types, (subtypes?) without having to call `toMover` every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model it differently:

```
type alias Mover =
  { x : Int
  , y : Int
  , kind : Kind
  }


type Kind = Enemy | Player 

enemy1 = Mover 0 0 Enemy -- these are shortcuts to item creation
player1 = Mover 2 2 Player 

enemy x y = Mover x y Enemy -- if you prefer functions 

player x y = Mover x y Player
```